# Removing duplicates dictionary from a list except one dictionary can be duplicate using python

Tags: python, duplicates

I have a list like

```
d=[{'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 8, 32, 35), 'temp': 39.1}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 9, 32, 35), 'temp': 39.1}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 9, 32, 35), 'temp': 39.1}, {'date': None, 'temp': None}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 11, 32, 35), 'temp': 39.1},{'date': None, 'temp': None}]
```

My output should be

```
d=[{'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 8, 32, 35), 'temp': 39.1}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 9, 32, 35), 'temp': 39.1},{'date': None, 'temp': None}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 11, 32, 35), 'temp': 39.1},{'date': None, 'temp': None}]
```

i.e it should remove all duplicate entries from a list except it should not remove if there is {'date': None, 'temp': None} as duplicates.
I had tried

```
result = [i for n, i in enumerate(d) if i not in d[n + 1:]]
```

But it is removing including {'date': None, 'temp': None} if there is duplicate. How can i do this using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay with non-list-comprehension solution, then try this:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for i in d:
...     if (i not in result) or (i == {'date': None, 'temp': None}):
...         result.append(i)
```

Comment: Yeah this is what i want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add an `or`:

```
result = [i for n, i in enumerate(d) if i not in d[n + 1:] or i == {'date': None, 'temp': None}]
```